# Move projectile in direction the gun is facing

Tags: java, mathematics, physics, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move sprite in the direction it is facing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37623/move-sprite-in-the-direction-it-is-facing)

I am attempting to have a projectile follow the direction a gun is facing. When using the following code I am unable to make the projectile go in the right direction.

```
float speed = .5f;

float dX = (float) -Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree)) * speed;
float dY = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * speed;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The degree is the direction the gun is facing in degree's.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work, not sure why the dx and dy do not go in the right direction. One problem I am having and I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it... but all I have is the center of the gun and the degree its facing, but I get the movement in other directions but the correct one.

Comment: What behavior are you observing?  Which direction does the projectile travel in relative to the gun?  What else have you tried?

Comment: I set the gun at 45 degrees and I get the bullets traveling at a right angle to it at approximately 315 degrees, I try and correct for it, but then it comes out at some other angle.

Comment: At 90 degrees the bullets travel straight down at approximately 270.

Comment: Try applying the unary `-` to `dY` instead of `dX`.

Comment: Cool.  I'll post an answer to wrap this up.

Comment: It's still a duplicate. It's just that you had trouble implementing it. That's a localized problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the behavior you were experiencing and the results of my suggestion in the comments, the problem is that you need to apply the unary `-` to the result of `Math.sin` instead of `Math.cos`.

This is probably a result of the correspondence you have between positive/negative rotation and clockwise/counterclockwise direction.

Comment: I thought I had tried that before, but I must be tired. This answer worked perfectly.